# Selenium with python using headless Chrome on MacOS - takes too long

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that logs into a site and then takes a screenshot. It uses Chrome 59 on MacOS in headless mode.

I have two problems, that I think are related. One problem is that my script takes minutes when it should take seconds. The second is that Chrome icon lingers in my Dock and never closes.

I think these problems are caused by the site that I am checking has a couple of elements that don't load. `\images\grey_semi.png` and `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` and I think this holds up selenium and prevents it from closing as instructed with `driver.close()`

What can I do?

script:

```
import os  
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"),   chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://url.com/")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("L1")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("name")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("P1")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element_by_id("login").click()
driver.get("https://url.com/Overview.aspx")
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('main-page.png')
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Job Board").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Available Deployments").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) in your code. As you know Web apps are using AJAX techniques to load dynamic data. When a page is loaded by the browser, the elements within that page may load at different time intervals. Depending from the implementation it is possible that the [load event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) is affected by the `google-analytics.com/analytics.js`, since a web page is considered completely loaded after all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.) is loaded. By default your UI Selenium tests use fresh instance of the browser, so it shouldn't cache the `analytics.js`. One more thing to check is if Google Analytics is placed in a specific place so that it isn't loaded until the page has loaded or run async. It used to be before the `</body>` tag but I believe it's now supposed to be the last `<script>` in the `<head>` tag. You can find more details of [Page Load Impact of Google Analytics here](https://mikekeran.com/node/1), they claim if done right, the load times are so small that it’s not even worth worrying about. My best guess is that the issue is with the how Google Analytics are used.

About your second problem

> Chrome icon lingers in my Dock and never closes

In case you see errors in browser console, try use the [quit()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.quit) method, it  closes the browser and shuts down the `ChromeDriver` executable that is started when starting the `ChromeDriver`. Keep in mind that `close()` is used to close the browser only, but the driver instance still remains dangling. Another thing to check is that you are actually using the latest versions of both `ChromeDriver` executable and Chrome browser.

*UPDATE:*

If waits do NOT affect your execution time, this means that Selenium will wait for the page to finish loading and then look for the elements you've specified. The only real option that I can think off is to [specify a page timeout](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) like so:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(seconds)
except TimeoutException:
    # put code with waits here
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `driver.quit()` is good enough for me. thanks
For the delay, I have tried `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` but it has the same effect. Can you guide me towards what kind of wait I should use in order to "wait 10 seconds and then click the damn button"?

Comment: For reference the google analytics script is right at the top and appears as `<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-96380300-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>`

Comment: it is almost always better to define and use [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits), as to google-analytics - if u can change the page code, include it in the `<head>` as last `<script>` according to their recommendation

Comment: i tried the two suggested explicit wait functions and it still takes around 4 minutes. i don't have control over the page to move the google analytics.